# alter table statements to enforce entity integrity

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, sqlplus

He guys I have the following the tables for ORACLE 10g and the problem is i am trying to enforce entity integrity on ALL tables. I have completed the first 4 but the last one is throwing an error. I have used the following code to alter the tables:

```
ALTER TABLE name ADD CONSTRAINT name PRIMARY KEY (name);

Actor (actorID, lastName, firstName, middleName, suffix, gender, birthDate, deathDate)
Movie (movieID, title, year, company, totalNoms, awardsWon, DVDPrice, discountPrice)
Quote (quoteID, quote)
Role (roleID ,roleName ,gender ,actorID* ,movieID*) 
RoleQuote (roleID*, quoteID*)
```

for the last table (RoleQuote) i have tried

```
ALTER TABLE name ADD CONSTRAINT name, name PRIMARY KEY (name, name);
```

but it is throwing this error:

```
invalid identifier
```

Can anyone help me thanks the tables have been created without error and they work flawless but the constraint on the last table (RoleQuote)is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD CONSTRAINT Constraint_name PRIMARY KEY (Field1_name, Field2_name);
```

Comment: How would i go about viewing my constraints any help would be appreciated thanks

Comment: @user1137472: Check http://www.shutdownabort.com/dbaqueries/Structure_Constraints.php

Comment: Need the syntax for the one above in answer if that is ok with you

Comment: Use the first query from the link I provided, just put your schema owner and table name instead of `&owner` and `&table_name`

Comment: That query does not match the constraint i added it will be like messing around with when i just keep trying me self the reason i ask for an example is I have this:
 
SELECT CONSTRAINT_NAME, TABLE_NAME,STATUS FROM USER_CONSTRAINTS WHERE TABLE_NAME=’TEACHER_GRADE’; 

But i dont understand what the "STATUS" means

Comment: you can find more info about all columns here http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_1037.htm#i1576022